Set Streamlit url with Docker
When running a streamlit app alone I am able to set the url of my app (in local) without problem.
For-example running a simple file Test.py like this :
import streamlit as st

# set the app's title
st.title("Very simple app")

with streamlit run Test.py --server.port=8501 --server.address=0.0.0.0 --server.baseUrlPath=/Testweb/ I am able to go to http://0.0.0.0:8501/Testweb/, which is the correct url I set.
But when using Docker, I cannot access to the correct url.
With following files (along with the previous Test.py, all at the same level) :
requirements.txt :
streamlit==1.30.0

and
Dockerfile :
# Use the official Python base image
FROM python:3.10.3

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file and install the dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the app code into the container
COPY . .

# Set the command to run the app
CMD ["sh", "-c", "streamlit run Test.py --server.port=8501 --server.address=0.0.0.0 --server.baseUrlPath=/Testweb/"]

with commands :
image building : docker build -t test-streamlit .
launch container : docker run -d --name test-streamlit-container test-streamlit
It does not work with the correct url. Instead, it partially works with a 'random' url like http://172.17.0.2:8501/Testweb/.
So it's like the port and the baseUrlPath are correctly passed on with Docker, but not the server address.
I also tried to add a config.toml, but once again, it's the server address that is not correctly passed on.
What am I doing wrong ? It is just running a simple streamlit app with docker in a complete local setup.
Thanks !

Your application setup is faultless. You just need to share the container port with the host.
To build the image:
docker build -t test-streamlit

To run the image:
docker run -p 8501:8501 test-streamlit

The vital component that gives you access to the app from your host machine is -p 8501:8501, which effectively creates a link from port 8501 on your host machine to port 8501 on the container.
You should be able to visit http://127.0.0.1:8501/Testweb/ on the host browser to see the test app.


My fault, I forgot to correctly set up port link from my machine to container... It works well now, thanks ! Also it's good when using a compose.yml with ports: - "8501:8501" (on two rows), then launching docker compose up -d.
